# Polymer - Prolems successfully sending core-ajax params

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I'm trying to get the values of some paper-radio-buttons and then pass them to a URL using core ajax. I'm having a hard time knowing if I am getting the values correctly and if I'm passing them to the URL.

When I get the button press:

```
<paper-button affirmative hover on-tap="{{addNewGraph}}">Submit</paper-button>
```

I call the following script:

```
<script>
    Polymer("add-graphItem",{
        addNewGraph: function () {
            var HeaderName = this.$.graphOptionsLoad.$.headerValue.selectedItem.label;
            var FunctionName = this.$.graphFunctionsLoad.$.functionValue.selectedItem.label;
            console.log("The options are " +HeaderName +" and " +FunctionName);
            this.$.sendOptions.go();
            console.log(sendOptions);
        },
    })
</script>
```

To use core-ajax I'm using:

```
<core-ajax auto url="/getGraph" method="POST" id="sendOptions"></core-ajax>
```

The `console.log(sendOptions);` throws me "Uncaught ReferenceError: sendOptions is not defined"

Wondering what I'm doing wrong and if anyone has any advice - thanks

Here's a plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/WPN3vG8LaKjuWyc0omrp?p=preview) that more or less replicates what I'm trying to do

Comment: core-ajax element is not a property of add-graphItem. You should put core-ajax inside it or use document.querySelector('#sendOptions') to fetch it

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but isn't core-ajax in add-graphItem (on line 63 of the plunkr?)

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. But then everything is working fine in Plunker, after selecting options from both lists.

Comment: But how do I check what it's sending and if it is correctly - I'm not sure that I'm grabbing the params and sending them to core-ajax and if the core-ajax is sending those to the URL (I think it is sending something to the URL but don't think it's the params)

Comment: See my full answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the ajax is really posts you should write target script on the server side, which can simply reply the incoming request. Then you should add event listener to core-response, see https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-ajax for details.

There is no params definition in the outgoing request in Plunker code. It can be done like this:

```
Polymer("add-graphItem", {
  addNewGraph: function () {
    var params = {};
    if (this.$.graphOptionsLoad.$.headerValue.selectedItem) {
      params['HeaderName'] = this.$.graphOptionsLoad.$.headerValue.selectedItem.label;
    }
    if (this.$.graphFunctionsLoad.$.functionValue.selectedItem) {
      params['FunctionName'] = this.$.graphFunctionsLoad.$.functionValue.selectedItem.label;
    }
    this.$.sendOptions.params = JSON.stringify(params);
    this.$.sendOptions.go();
    console.log(params);
  },
});
```

Comment: This seems to have worked - still need to write a target script on the server side to test it - but thanks for walking through it with me!